# How can I only make one wudu because of cream?

Tags: salat, wudu, prayer-timings

I have a skin problem (on my face) and I am required to put a very expensive cream on my face once a day and cannot wash it off. The cream has to be on my face all the time. When I wake up for fajr prayer I do wudu (then put the cream) and then I have to try and not go to the bathroom the whole day until after isha prayer so I don't break the wudu. It's very difficult because I eat and drink less and have to only pray with one wudu only. I don't know what to do or if what i'm doing is ok.

What should I do?

Comment: Consult a mufti with specific details for personalized verdicts. This is not a fatwa site.

Comment: "What should I do" generally attracts subjective answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i don't know about what you can do to do not try  not go to the bathroom the whole day
but about your question (or if what i'm doing is ok.)
yes what you do is ok
 Renewing wudu is suna , not a duty
and prophet Mohamed did what you do in tabok foray (غزوة تبوك) he pray all the prayer with one wudu  when shaba ask hem he said that 'because i want you to know this possible "
but Renewing wudu in every pray is better the god say (يا ايها الذين ءامنوا اذا قمتم الي الصلاة فأغسلوا وجوهكم وايديكم الي المرافق وامسحوا برؤسكم وارجلكم الي الكعبين )
the god say if we want to pray we have to do wudu but because what prophet mohammed do in Tabok's foray  we say that Renewing wudu is not a duty every pray but is better
link for the fatwa in arabic https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/281650/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%A1-%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%AF-%D9%83%D9%84-%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9

link for fatwa in english
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/239934/is-it-mustahabb-to-do-wudoo-before-every-naafil-prayer

Comment: This is irrelevant. The OP is not asking whether it is possible to pray with a single wudu, they are saying that they have trouble maintaining it for so long.

Comment: I don't know what to do or if what i'm doing is ok.>>> this the question or i am wrong? the second half of the question  if what i'm doing is ok